# Confusion regarding the proof of Heine-Borel theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In the proof of the Heine-Borel theorem given [here](https://youtu.be/7n7wV8s3jpc?t=708), the author demonstrates a proof that $[a,b]$ always has a finite subcover. In course of the proof, I've encountered the following set construction, $S=\{x\in [a,b]:[a,x] \text{ has a finite subcover}\}$. My question is the following: how can we assume that $[a,x]$ has a finite subcover, when we are trying to prove that $[a,b]$ has finite subcovering for every cover?

Comment: @jjagmath I have updated the title. Can you remove the downvote please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't assume that $[a,x]$ has a finite subcover.

We **define** the set $S$ as the set of all values $x$ **for which** $[a,x]$ has a finite subcover.

That is, for a given value of $x\in [a,b]$, we define $x$ to be in the set $S$ if and only if the set $[a,x]$ has a finite subcover. Under that definition, we don't assume anything about $x$. In fact, just with that definition, we don't yet **know** if any value is in the set $S$. For all we know, $S$ might be empty! But whatever $S$ is, we have a clear method of determining what elements are in $S$ and which are not. And that is what matters.

(of course, we prove that $S=[a,b]$, but that only comes later on in the proof)

For review, this is what the proof looks like:

1. Define $S=\{x|[a,x]\text{ has a finite subcover}\}$.
2. Do some magic.
3. Conclude that $b\in S$.
4. Therefore, $[a,b]$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: Okay! The finite subcover that we define for $[a,x]$, do we include that set in the final finite subcover of $[a,b]$? My confusion is that, the subcover must itself be a subset of the cover (which the author had defined previously). How does defining a subcover for $[a,x]$ help in determining the subcovering of $[a,b]$ w.r.t the already defined cover?

Comment: @vicky We don't "define a subcover for $[a,x]$". Where do you see the author defining a subcover for $[a,x]$?

Comment: Got it! Thanks.